# Scraping the HTML Table Data in Excel Sheet using Selinium and Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm looking to scrap the HTML table data from [here](http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/histstock.php)
and store that data into excel sheet using the Python and selenium, xlrd, xlwt, urllib2 modules. The real problem is after filling the some details to the page it's redirecting someurl, and placing the that URL into `urllib.open()` function, but showing the table information as empty.

```
import os,requests,time,xlrd,xlwt
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/histstock.php")
browser.maximize_window()
browser.find_element_by_link_text("INDEX").click()

index_list=["--Index--","S&P BSE Sensex","CNX Nifty","S&P BSE Smallcap","S&P BSE Midcap","S&P BSE 100","S&P BSE 200","S&P BSE 200","S&P BSE BANKEX","S&P BSE Capital Goods","S&P BSE Capital Goods","S&P BSE Metals","S&P BSE IT","S&P BSE Auto","S&P BSE Healthcare","S&P BSE Healthcare","S&P BSE Realty","S&P BSE TECk","S&P BSE PSU","S&P BSE Consumer Durables","S&P BSE Consumer Durables","S&P BSE SHARIAH","S&P BSE IPO","CNX Midcap Index -NSE","CNX Nifty Junior","CNX DEFTY","Nifty Midcap 50","CNX 100","CNX 500","Bank Nifty","CNX IT","CNX REALTY","CNX INFRA","CNX INFRA","CNX FMCG","CNX FMCG","CNX PHARMA","CNX PSE","CNX PSU BANK","CNX SERVICE","CNX SERVICE","CNX SERVICE","CNX SERVICE","CNX SERVICE"]
frm_day=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
frm_mnth=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June","July","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
frm_year=[2015,2014,2013,2012,2011,2010,2009,2008,2007,2006,2005,2004,2003,2002,2001,2000]
for i in frm_day:
    """browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='indian_indices']/option[3]")"""
    select_indices=browser.find_element_by_name("indian_indices").send_keys(index_list[i+1])
    link=browser.find_element_by_name("frm_dy").send_keys(frm_day[i+1])
    browser.find_element_by_name("frm_mth").send_keys(frm_mnth[i+1])
    browser.find_element_by_name("frm_yr").send_keys(frm_year[i+1])
    browser.find_element_by_name("to_dy").send_keys(frm_day[i])
    browser.find_element_by_name("to_mth").send_keys(frm_mnth[i])
    browser.find_element_by_name("to_yr").send_keys(frm_year[i])
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/center[2]/div/div/div[5]/div[4]/div[2]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/div[4]/input[1]").click()
    break
```

After executing the code the page is redirecting to otherpage.from on that page I need the table's data, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use "browser.current_url", this return url of page which contain table.Pass this url in browser.get(browser.current_url) and iterate table.

Answer (score 0):

`store=find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id='wmd-input']')
print(store.text)`
got the redirected page table data using above code.and all the data stored into text file and converted into Excel Sheet/CSV.
thank you. http://stackoverflow.com.